# "Cannot insert duplicate key in object" when deleting entries

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I know this sounds ridiculous, but I keep getting an error telling me that I cannot insert a duplicate key when trying to delete records in my database. My code is is quite basic

```
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                    this.DataSource.ParameterGroupEntries.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dataBaseParameterEntries);
                    this.DataSource.SubmitChanges();
                    this.DataSource.ParameterGroupEntries.InsertAllOnSubmit(localParameterEntries.ToArray());
                    this.DataSource.SubmitChanges();

                    scope.Complete();
            }
```

However on the `SubmitChanges()` right after the `DeleteAllOnSubmit(dataBaseEntries)` command, I keep getting the exception "Cannot insert duplicate key in object." I have tried breaking this up into two separate transactions, and even using `DeleteOnSubmit()` with a `foreach` loop and even removing the insert statement. No matter what, I get this error. This has really stumped me because I am not inserting any records, I am deleting them. Any advice?

**UPDATE:**
Upon removing the key constraint that was giving me trouble seemed to work. But since I am not the creator of the database, this is not really the most desirable choice.

Comment: Is it possible that a trigger on your delete is firing and inserting records into another table?

Comment: No it is not. In fact the Unique key constraint that is being violated is made of values that only appear on this table.

Comment: if you inspect `dataBaseParameterEntries` on the delete, are there any duplicate keys in there or are the values distinct?

Comment: no, but there are some in `localParameterEntries` that overlap. But this is the whole point of deleting the database entries first, so no overlaps will occur on submit. Also see my update.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any outstanding insert/updates from before the DeleteAllOnSubmit? You can try looking at this.DataSource.GetChangeSet() to see what the submit is doing or else using SQLProfiler to examine the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a problem with your seed, may be the seed value is out of synch with the existing table values.

You should call

```
dbcc checkident(TableName, reseed, Value)
```

and make value something less than the current value.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check for change before transaction scope, remove all inside the transaction scope and leave only 1 SubmitChanges() and scope.complete() to check for changes (insertion of duplicate record key)